# Check if regex starts at the beginning of the string or after specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a regex pattern. I want to check if it matches at the beginning of the string or after a new line or after a white space.

I also would like to make sure it matches the end of the string, after a new line or a white space.

How do I make this condition "beginning or white space" ? Do I have to repeat myself

Example:

"Crazy Fredrick bought many very exquisite opal jewels"

The search for `s` should only match the last character "s" in "jewels". The "s" in "exquisite" should not match.

Comment: @TomZych thanks. edited

Comment: split the words on space and check the last word (`[length -1]`) no need for regex here

Comment: one specific question **with code that is not working** and why it is not working per question

Answer (score 0):

This code is a regular expression starting with T and ending with s.Now if you want to check for each word in sentence split it by space and then use regular expression as per your requirement.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegularExpression {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(T).*[s]$");
   Matcher m = p.matcher("This is testingsd");
   System.out.println(m.matches());
   }
}
```

Comment: A java answer for a javascript question?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can use the character `\b`, which according to [MDN's RegExp page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

> Matches a zero-width word boundary, such as between a letter and a
>   space.

So to match the s in the word "jewels" in your example, I would use the regex:

```
var regex = /s\b/g;
```

To match every word that ends with "y", I can use

```
var regex = /\w*y\b/gi;
```

and it would produce the result "Crazy, very, many".